# How to make your TextView background transparent?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm creating the login page in Android Studio and I got problem with building the project.

In one tutorial, it was shown that including `#1100000` hexacode will help to make Text transparent, it does, however when I build program it gives error of

```
error: '#1100000' is incompatible with attribute android:background (attr) reference|color.
```

I have checked one question which says to add `@android:color/transparent` , however that doesn't help. Any recommendations?

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_pass"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_pass"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="#1100000"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Comment: If you check it with alpha attribute

Comment: May be issue is in android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_pass" this line. Otherwise @android:color/transparent should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a color value resource

`<color name="color_transparent">#00FFFFFF</color>`
in `colors.xml`  under values directory

Then use it as background in your textview as:

```
android:background="@color/color_transparent"
```

Normally, textviews come transparent out of the box, so please check attributes of the parent layout first.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: dulu noted although it was to the point question and so was the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Please, just read the description. I have already mentioned that one doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a 0. `#1100000` should be `#11000000`.

> The value always begins with a pound (#) character and then followed
>   by the Alpha-Red-Green-Blue information in one of the following
>   formats:
>
> - #RGB
> - #ARGB
> - #RRGGBB
> - #AARRGGBB

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Color

Alpha channel represents the transparency value. 
Some examples:

```
100% - FF
95% - F2
90% - E6
85% - D9
80% - CC
75% - BF
70% - B3
65% - A6
60% - 99
55% - 8C
50% - 80
45% - 73
40% - 66
35% - 59
30% - 4D
25% - 40
20% - 33
15% - 26
10% - 1A
5% - 0D
0% - 00
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your comment, but I have tried it too. It gives the same error when I build the program.